# google map: get max/min zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to know the maximum zoom in / zoom out level on my map. So far I could do this:

```
 this.mapInstance.cachedZoomLevel = this.mapInstance.getZoom();

 this.mapInstance.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
            console.log('zoom changed from :' + this.cachedZoomLevel + ' to ' + this.getZoom());
            this.cachedZoomLevel = this.getZoom();
 });
```

From the above code I can tell if the user is trying to zoom in or zoom out and also the current zoom level of the map after zooming in/out. But, I dont know how to determine if the current level is max or min.

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal zoom (*"maximal zoom-out"*) is 0 if I remember correctly. To find out maximal possible zoom-in, you need to use `MaxZoomService`:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom

The reason is that it changes across the map and with different tiles you use.

The best way I see is to take your current viewport center and get max zoom from that point. If the user zooms-in/out, you can take that event's zooming point to determine the max.